# Error while executing e2e tests for angular 8, protractor

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor

After executing the CLI command (ng e2e) this is the error I am getting in the console:

```
USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: 
A device attached to the system is not functioning
```

Further information and versions:

- Windows 10
- Angular 8
- chromedriver_87.0.4280.20.exe
- node v12.9.1 (tested with latest i.e. 14.x)
- protractor v7.0.0

This is driving me mad, and I am not able to debug it or find much information otherwise online.

Comment: weird... just out of curiosity have you tried unplugging all your usb devices and running it

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov interestingly there is no USB connected.

Comment: okay, can you post your config, there might be something wrong about how you launch your browser

Comment: Mostly out of the box config that you get from creating new angular project

Comment: unfortunately I setup projects manually in the past. Can you upload your config?

Comment: So I found this link and an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR; (and the whole story): It was happening in a particular version of the Chrome driver.

As pointed out by [Celia Gaylard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5074377/celia-gaylard) in another thread the issue seems to be with logging.

We ignored the issue for a while and after some update, it vanished into the same thin air it came from.

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer only to state that I have been experiencing the same issue for approximately a month, and thus far I have not found a solution.
What I have tried is:
removing all USBs and SD Cards, and extended screen cables.
I rebooted my laptop -still a problem.
I did npm install and updated all drivers - I still see the usb messages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio

I found the answer in the link